# Automatically add incoming .ics calendar invites to my iCloud calendar

Tags: mac, apple-mail, calendar.app

Is there a way for Mail on my Mac to automatically add .ics calendar invites to my iCloud calendar?  I am used to Outlook automatically showing calendar invites as tentative in my calendar, but with Apple tools I need to explicitly click on the .ics file to have it show up in my calendar.  Embarrassingly, I've already missed a couple meetings because of this - and really want to see all my invites in my calendar automatically.  I'm desparate for a solution and using 3rd party software or scripting is fine if it solves the problem!

Comment: Would like to know how to do this as well.